# DSolve::dvnoarg. Where is my error?

Tags: differential-equations

It's one of my first attempts on Mathematica, and I do not know where is my mistake.

[image: The equation]

Comment: Try `theta[T]` instead of just `theta` .  also not good idea to use UpperCase single letters for variables in Mathematica. stick to all lower case for everything. Also, are you sure the forcing function if in terms of `x`? What is `x` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to get a solution is rewrite your code as

```
 DSolveValue[θ'[t]/(k t) == -1/x^2, θ[t], t]
```

which evaluates to

```
 -((k t^2)/(2 x^2)) + C[1]
```

If you don't want the constant of integration, add an initial condition to your system.

```
 DSolveValue[{θ'[t]/(k t) == -1/x^2, θ[0] == 0}, θ[t], t]
```

> `-((k t^2)/(2 x^2))`

Comment: It worked fine, thank you very much!

Comment: @Eric. Since you found this answer helpful, it will benefit both of us if you were to click on the checkmark that you see on the left-hand side to show that you accept it.